# Can't install USB WiFi driver in Windows guest running in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, linux, wireless-networking, virtualbox

I installed Windows 7 on VirtualBox 4.3 with Ubuntu as host.

I have a TP-LINK 722 USB WiFi adapter which I want to use in the guest.
In the virtual machine, from the USB devices section, I selected *Atheros USB adapter*.
Then I installed the drivers and the utility, and the guest **does** recognize the adapter.

But Windows isn't able to load the drivers for the adapter.
In Device Manager, it displays it with the warning sign and it says

> "This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31)"

I also have a live Kali Linux in VirtualBox, which also doesn't show the USB adapter, while in Ubuntu the adapter works as soon as I plug it in.

I'm on Ubuntu 15.04, installed on an external hard drive connected to an HP laptop via USB cable, to a USB 2.0 port.

I do have the guest addition and extension packs installed.

Comment: Any reason you want to have it directly connected to your VM? As you said it is working on the host, so you should have network connectivity with the vNIC in the guest.

Comment: yeah it's for a windows only app.i don't want it for internet.

Comment: meaning the windows app has to see the wireless adapter? if you just want to have it connected to another network through the wifi then you should try to use the bridged network connection select the wifi adapter and connect to the desired network on your host. And of course you should check the windows logs to see what it says about why it fails.

Comment: i need the adapter to be only in windows, bridge didn't work.the windows does find the adapter it even knows it's tp-link adapter but it can't load the drivers for it therefor the app i want to use doesn't find any wireless adapter

Comment: Maybe this youtube video will resolve your issue (it's not the same but similar) here the link: [Connect USB Wireless Adapter to Kali Linux in Virtualbox](https://youtu.be/K1ETBeRQBs4)